# Редирект в Apache с http на https в web 1c

Tags: apache, 1с, https

Делал веб-публикацию 1с-ных баз на Linux. Поставил Apache из исходников с модулем `ssl` и `rewrite`. Отдельно компилировал модуль 1с. Все уже работает по `https`.

Нужно сделать редирект всех запросов с `http` на `https`.
Как это можно сделать, не используя `.htaccess` и без системы выртуальных хостов?

Xотелось бы весь редирект настроить в одном файлике `httpd.conf`, т.к. там лежит весь конфиг баз `1с`.
Конфиг в таком виде для каждой базы:

```
Alias "/base_1" "/var/www/html/base_1"
<Directory "/var/www/html/base_1">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    SetHandler 1c-application
    ManagedApplicationDescriptor "/var/www/html/base_1/default.vrd"
</Directory>
```

Возможно, можно вписать в него?

Answer (score 1):

согласно [wiki проекта apache использование *virtualhost* «is simpler and safer»](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL).

но, в принципе, как там же и [упомянуто](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS), можно (но не рекомендуется) сделать перенаправление и без использования *virtualhost* (т.е., глобально для всего сервера):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Неоднократно сталкивался с подобным методом, вот только как его глобально прописать без `htaccess` в `https.conf`? Чеез `<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>`
 не работает.

Comment: согласно [документации](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), для всех трёх упомянутых директив возможны все возможные четыре контекста: server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess. секция ifmodule — это всего лишь проверка доступности указанного модуля. если вы не собираетесь его отключать, то эту секцию можно смело опустить.

Answer (score 0):

Удалить:

```
Options None
```

Вставить:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```